Can I set de visibility (permissions) by swminlanes?
I have a board in Azure DevOps with three lanes: two for internal teams and one for fabriq, named 'Parcerias.'
I need the Parcerias team to only see the 'Parcerias' swimlane. I thought about creating two boards, but I want the entire project overview in one board.
If it can´t be possible, can I create subareas and one of my subarea only see this especific subarea? Can I put de work itens of this subarea to appears in the main area only for internal teams?


I need the Parcerias team to only see the 'Parcerias' swimlane.

I am afraid that there is no such permission can limit team to only see one Swimlane in Kanban Boards.
If users in the team have access to the Kanban board, they will be able to see all Swimlanes.
I can fully understand your requirement. You can submit a suggest ticket in the site: Developer Community to report this feature

can I create subareas and one of my subarea only see this especific subarea? Can I put de work itens of this subarea to appears in the main area only for internal teams?

Yes. This can be achieved.
Here are the steps:
Step1: Create Subareas in the Project Settings -> Team Configuration.
For example:

Step2: You can Enable the permission: View work items in this node in the target subarea security. And Disable the permission in other subareas.
For example:

In this case, the target team can only see work items in the one of the subareas in Kanban board.
For example:


You help me a lot! Many thanks!
